# TortoiseSVN very slow on some windows configurations

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, performance

I’m experiencing performance issues with tortoiseSVN client and xp-dev server :
It take 19 minutes to check out 718kBytes in 297 files !
PC is running windows XP, latest version of T-SVN. I’ve disabled firewall and antivirus with the same result.
I made another test on a second machine (same internet connexion, antivirus and firewall on) running Vista and it takes 19 seconds !
So it looks like it’s not an internet connexion nor an antivirus/firewall problem.

Any clue what it can be ? Maybe I have to configure something on the XP machine ? Subversion config ?

Help greatly appreciated to solve this very annoying problem.

Julien

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this related quesiton: [Why is TortoiseSVN so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458394/why-is-tortoisesvn-so-slow)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out : the problem happens on my 3''5 external drive (that I use for my work projects). I can't believe it took me so long to find it :-(
I still don't understand why it causes such a huge performance hit though (I guess that's why it took me so long).
Of course I understand that USB2 is slower than my internal drives (I've worked on this drive for several years with no problem with other applications) but with SVN it's not just slower : it's unusable !
I was thinking that the performance bottleneck would be on the connexion speed but I was wrong...

Anyway if it can avoid someone troubles : don't work with Tortoise/SVN on an external USB2 drive, at least on windows XP.

Cheers,

Julien